# Use Google DataTable in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, google-visualization

I am trying to use information from Google's datatable to display in highcharts. I have the table in the variable called "data" but when I used my data variable for the charts data it does not work. Any advice? I would like to display elevation on the y axis.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Sample');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Elevation');
        for (var i = 0; i < elevations.length; i++) {
          data.addRow(['', elevations[i].elevation*3.28084]); // convert meters to feet


   }

    var myChart = Highcharts.chart('elevation_chart', {
     chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Elevation'

    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Elevation'
        }
    },
    series: [{

        data: data

    }]
});
```

Comment: have you tried to see output of `console.log(data)` does this match as per data required by highcharts

Comment: Why are you using highcharts instead of the google chart?  It seems an odd mix of libraries.  Your problem is that the DataTable object isn't the same form HighCharts wants: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.data.  If you want to use HighCharts, you'll need to transform the data into one of the acceptable formats.  But, if you want to use Google charts, it's in the exact format Google wants: http://jsfiddle.net/YolandaMDavis/Qquse/

Comment: Google Charts doesn't seem very mobile friendly. Not responsive. Cannot seem to be able to drag index point marker along the graph.